# Is it possible to delete records from Hive external table with AWS S3 bucket as location?

Tags: amazon-s3, hive, iics-di

Is it possible to delete records from Hive external table with AWS S3 bucket as location using IICS.

For example : DELETE FROM MY_HIVE_TABLE WHERE COLUMN1='TEST1';

Comment: the table is not transactional i guess, right?

Comment: not transactional.

Answer (score 0):

You can not delete from hive(unless they are kudu).

As per your comment, i think you can add a filter transformation right before target hive S3 table with condition `COLUMN1<>'TEST1'`

And then overwrite the hive target table in S3 using IICS.

This will overwrite same table with everything but COLUMN1=TEST1 i.e. deleting the data.

Comment: Thanks Koushik for your response. However I need to perform the delete operation with IICS target as hive AWS  S3 and MS SQL server table as source. Could you please advice how I can perform in that context.

Comment: In iics can you put a filter right before target. I mentioned this in details in my answer.

Comment: Here the source is Microsoft SQL Server table. And we are pulling the new data (delta) using a control table in PostgreSQL. Then before writing this delta to Hive we need to remove existing data matching to that month in the delta from Hive.